# Reformatting string in List - Python

Tags: python, string, list, reformatting

I have a list that I'm trying to reformat.

```
data = ['Height:\n      \n      6\' 4"', 'Weight:\n      \n      185 lbs.', 'Reach:\n      \n      80"', 'STANCE:\n      \n      Switch', 'DOB:\n      \n      \n        Jul 22, 1989', 'SLpM:\n          \n\n          3.93', 'Str. Acc.:\n          \n          49%', 'SApM:\n          \n          2.67', 'Str. Def:\n          \n          59%', '', 'TD Avg.:\n          \n          0.00', 'TD Acc.:\n          \n          0%', 'TD Def.:\n          \n          78%', 'Sub. Avg.:\n          \n          0.2']
```

I've tried using strip.

```
for info in data:
        info.strip('\n      \n      ')
```

But, I'm  still getting the same output.

How would I be able to delete the whitespace of "\n      \n      " within each index of the list. To get the following?

```
data = ['Height: 6\' 4"', 'Weight: 185 lbs.', 'Reach: 80"', 'STANCE: Switch', 'DOB: Jul 22, 1989', 'SLpM: 3.93', 'Str. Acc.: 49%', 'SApM: 2.67', 'Str. Def: 59%', '', 'TD Avg.: 0.00', 'TD Acc.: 0%', 'TD Def.: 78%', 'Sub. Avg.: 0.2']
```

Comment: `strip()` returns a new string. It does not affect the original.

Comment: Plus, `strip()` won't remove the whitespace inside the string. Only at the ends.

Comment: Maybe build a new list and use regex: `data = [re.sub(r"\s+", ' ') for info in data]`

Comment: same idea @JohnnyMopp ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach: Replace the colon and the following blank spaces with a colon and a space:

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile(r":\s*")
new_data = [
    pattern.sub(": ", datum)
    for datum in data
]
```

`new_data` then become:

```py
['Height: 6\' 4"',
 'Weight: 185 lbs.',
 'Reach: 80"',
 'STANCE: Switch',
 'DOB: Jul 22, 1989',
 'SLpM: 3.93',
 'Str. Acc.: 49%',
 'SApM: 2.67',
 'Str. Def: 59%',
 '',
 'TD Avg.: 0.00',
 'TD Acc.: 0%',
 'TD Def.: 78%',
 'Sub. Avg.: 0.2']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```py
import re

def remove_multiple_ws(s: str) -> str:
    return re.sub(r"\s+", " ", str(s))


data = [remove_multiple_ws(s) for s in data]
```

Comment: An answer that contains an explanation is much better than just "try this"

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to substitute any duplicate spaces and more.

From the documentation:

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```

> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl. If the pattern isn’t found, string is returned unchanged.

This is a way that `re.sub` could be used in this situation:

```
>>> import re
>>> mystring = ' string    string \t\n\n string'
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\s+')
>>> pattern.sub(" ", mystring)
'string string string'
```

Using this method, an implementation for your code would look something like this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\s+")
new_data = [pattern.sub(" ",part) for part in data]
```

Here is what `new_data` should be:

```
kali@kali:~$ python3 test.py -i
>>> new_data
['Height: 6\' 4"',
 'Weight: 185 lbs.',
 'Reach: 80"',
 'STANCE: Switch',
 'DOB: Jul 22, 1989',
 'SLpM: 3.93',
 'Str. Acc.: 49%',
 'SApM: 2.67',
 'Str. Def: 59%',
 '',
 'TD Avg.: 0.00',
 'TD Acc.: 0%',
 'TD Def.: 78%',
 'Sub. Avg.: 0.2']
```

if you want to learn more about regex in python here are some useful links:

- [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)
- [google developers page about regex](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions)
- [w3school regex python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp)
- [programiz python regex with examples](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/regex)